# How to silence a function's output to console?

Tags: python, function, printing, console, nested

I have several functions and I only want output from the outermost function call. For example:

```
def f1():
    print 'foo'

def f2(boo=True):
    f1()
    if boo:
        print 'bar'     
    else:
        print 'black sheep'

def f3():
    f2()
    print 'shh!!!'  

f2(True)
print
f2(False)
print 
f3()
```

The above script outputs:

```
foo
bar

foo
black sheep

foo
bar
shh!!!
```

The desired output:

```
bar

black sheep

shh!!!
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the code inside the functions `f2`, `f3`?

Comment: I think `logging` could help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is allowed to modify the code inside `f2`, `f3` then one way would be use a custom context manager which assigns `sys.stdout` to something else, and at exit of that context manager reassign `sys.stdout` to the original STDOUT.

```
import sys, StringIO

class Supress_print(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        sys.stdout = self.stdout

def f1():
    print 'foo'

def f2(boo=True):
    with Supress_print():
        f1()
    if boo:
        print 'bar'
    else:
        print 'black sheep'

def f3():
    with Supress_print():
        f2()
    print 'shh!!!'  

f2(True)
print
f2(False)
print 
f3()
```

**Output:**

```
bar

black sheep

shh!!!
```

---

**Update:**

```
import sys, inspect, functools, StringIO

def supress_print(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        #print inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[3][3], func.__name__
        if inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[3][3] != 'main':
            stdout = sys.stdout
            sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
            val = func(*args, **kwargs)
            sys.stdout = stdout
            return val
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@supress_print
def f1():
    print 'foo'


@supress_print
def f2(boo=True):
    f1()
    if boo:
        print 'bar'
    else:
        print 'black sheep'

def f3():
    f2()
    print 'shh!!!'
```

Comment: what if i am only allowed to change `f3()` but not `f2()`?

Comment: @alvas I've added another solution using decorator and inspect module, haven't tested it thoroughly though. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Use inspect

```
import inspect
def f1():
    if (len(inspect.stack())) <= 2:
        print 'foo'

def f2(boo=True):
    f1()
    if boo:
        if (len(inspect.stack())) <= 2:
            print 'bar'     
    else:
        if (len(inspect.stack())) <= 2:
            print 'black sheep'

def f3():
    f2()
    if (len(inspect.stack())) <= 2:
        print 'shh!!!'  

f2(True)
print
f2(False)
print 
f3()
```